# Make error_log readable by apache

Tags: apache-2.2, php, permissions, logging

Setup: CentOS 6.6, Apache 2.2.15, php 5.5.21

I 'm building a php script that displays the content of the `/var/log/httpd/error_log` file. Unfortunately, it does not work. The error message states:

> Permission denied in
>   /var/www/domain.com/tools/server-logs-viewer.php on line 405

Line 405:  `$f = fopen($filename, "rb");`

I've chmoded 0777 the file, just to check, still no-go. So I assume the message refers to file ownership. The log file is owned by root:root whereas the php script is owned by apache:apache.

What can I do to give apache enough read access to the file, without compromising the error reporting process ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I has been ages that I am not doing anything in PHP but, without further info there would be a couple system configuration elements and php.ini settings I would check:

**path to the log file**

Please, ensure that the user running apache is able to reach the directory where the file is. That means it should have r+x access to the directories along the path.

**php.ini settings**

Please, have a look at the php [fopen manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

- safe_mode: depending on the version you are using (it seems it was removed in 5.4.0)
- open_basedir: refuses to open anything not in this tree.

**SELinux, AppArmor**

Are you running SELinux or AppArmor? That could prevent the apache process to access the file despite of the permissions.

Best regards

Comment: Your very first advise was the right trick, thank you